# Output MySQL data in Modal

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, mdbootstrap

I've looked for a solution to my issue and found a few using AJAX. However, they're not working for me. Is there any way to do this without AJAX?
I've put together a little portal for me to view my client's information and I'm trying to output some MySQL data in an MDBootstrap Modal. Everything is functional except for the part where the modal comes in (only the first DB row comes in). Here's what I have so far.

````
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","dbpass","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM clients");

echo "<table id='clientsInfo' class='table table-striped table-bordered table-sm cellspacing=0 width=100%'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class='th-sm'>Client
      </th>
      <th class='th-sm'>Website URL
      </th>
      <th class='th-sm'>cPanel
      </th>
      <th class='th-sm'>Webmail
      </th>
      <th class='th-sm'>Website Admin
      </th>
      <th class='th-sm'>Cloudflare
      </th>
      <th class='th-sm'>Client Info
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tbody>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['client_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a target='_blank' href='" . $row['website_url'] . "'><button type='button' class='btn blue-gradient btn-sm'>Click Here</button></a></td>";
echo "<td><a target='_blank' href='" . $row['cpanel'] . "'><button type='button' class='btn peach-gradient btn-sm'>Click Here</button></a></td>";
echo "<td><a target='_blank' href='" . $row['webmail'] . "'><button type='button' class='btn purple-gradient btn-sm'>Click Here</button></a></td>";
echo "<td><a target='_blank' href='" . $row['web_admin'] . "'><button type='button' class='btn blue-gradient btn-sm'>Click Here</button></a></td>";
echo "<td><a target='_blank' href='" . $row['cloudflare'] . "'><button type='button' class='btn peach-gradient btn-sm'>Click Here</button></a></td>";
echo "<td><button type='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#fullHeightModalRight' class='btn btn purple-gradient btn-sm'>Client Info</button></td>
<!-- Client Info Modal -->
<div class='modal fade right' id='fullHeightModalRight' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='clientInfoLabel'
  aria-hidden='true'>

  <!-- Add class .modal-full-height and then add class .modal-right (or other classes from list above) to set a position to the modal -->
  <div class='modal-dialog modal-full-height modal-right' role='document'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <h4 class='modal-title w-100' id='clientInfoLabel'>Hello World</h4>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
          <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-body'>
      " . $row['client_info'] . "
      </div>
      <div class='modal-footer justify-content-center'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Client Info Modal -->";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</tbody>";
}
echo "<tfoot>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Client";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>Website URL";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>cPanel";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>Webmail";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>Website Admin";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>Cloudflare";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>Client Info";
echo "</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</tfoot>";
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>```
````

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the problem? What do you mean by only a few rows? Does it go off the screen? What's happening?

Comment: @Difster so here's how it's going. The red works, the blue should be showing data from each row, however it's only showing content from the first one. http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2019/12/27/0030/2126/1972302/02/bd5965418e.jpg
http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2019/12/27/0030/2126/1972302/02/f93c1d29ad.jpg
http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2019/12/27/0030/2126/1972302/02/c539a36a8d.jpg

Comment: As you have updated your code and fixed some issues like fixed the sortability issue, update the code here on SO also so that we can check how you have changed the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `<tbody>` from the loop and place it before the loop. Also put `</tbody>` after the loop.

Also, remove this modal from the loop and paste it before the `</body>` tag at the end of your `HTML` section.

```
<!-- Client Info Modal -->
<div class='modal fade right' id='fullHeightModalRight' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='clientInfoLabel'
  aria-hidden='true'>

  <!-- Add class .modal-full-height and then add class .modal-right (or other classes from list above) to set a position to the modal -->
  <div class='modal-dialog modal-full-height modal-right' role='document'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <h4 class='modal-title w-100' id='clientInfoLabel'>Hello World</h4>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
          <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-body' id="dynamic_contents"></div>
      <div class='modal-footer justify-content-center'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Client Info Modal -->
```

I have just added the id for the modal body `dynamic_contents`

Then add an AJAX function as specified below.

```
function open_modal(contents=null){
    $('#dynamic_contents').html(contents);
    $('#fullHeightModalRight').modal();
}
```

then for the `client_info` button, add a trigger for `onClick` as below.

```
echo '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn purple-gradient btn-sm" onclick="open_modal(\''.$row['client_info'].'\')">Client Info</button></td>';
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this contribution. It fixed the sortability error I was having. However, the issue with data output to modal is still persisting.

Comment: Great! This worked. You had a small typo by the onClick as openModal, edited to open_modal. Thank you once again.